# VBA Type mismatch when passing form objects

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch

As a newbie (go easy on me :-), I'm getting a type mismatch when passing information through from a function.

```
' Generate Data Sub Function
Sub Send_listbox_list_to_function()

' Function to Create and populate the class
' -> Require's the listbox and the directory location

If Right(frmMain.txtDIR, 1) = "\" Then
    Call Create_Class(frmMain.lstDIR, frmMain.txtDIR.Value)
Else
    Call Create_Class(frmMain.lstDIR, frmMain.txtDIR.Value + "\")
End If

End Sub
```

This is function I'm trying to pass information through.

```
Sub Create_Class(ByRef lstbox As ListBox, ByVal loc As String)

' Generic Checksheet
Dim checksheet As cls_DR

End Sub
```

Is this possible in VBA? I'm worried its a timing error when using forms. that I can't get my head around. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameter is declared as the wrong sort of `Listbox` (there is also one in the Excel library). You need to use this:

```
Sub Create_Class(ByRef lstbox As MSForms.ListBox, ByVal loc As String)
```